# Is "Nagilum" the name of the species, or the creature in the void (or both)?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In "[Where Silence Has Lease](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Where_Silence_Has_Lease_(episode))", the Enterprise is trapped in a "void" by an entity which addresses itself as Nagilum. Is "Nagilum" the creature's name, or is it the species' name? Or perhaps both (as is apparently true with the Q)?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The official [Star Trek Encyclopedia](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Encyclopedia) has this to offer on the subject:

> ***Hole in Space*** - A spatial phenomenon created by the extra-dimensional **being called Nagilum**

The clear implication is that Nagilum is its name.

Answer (score 0):

It is the name of the creature that spoke to Picard.  The name is "Muligan" spelled backward, as actor Richard Mulligan was originally supposed to voice the creature.

Comment: This is interesting, but it doesn't really shed any light on the question at hand.